# как получить все документы (миллион записей) в результате запроса?

Tags: elasticsearch

К примеру, есть индекс, в нем миллион записей. 
Каждая запись - это адрес с координатами.

Я хочу получить все точки в запросе, чтобы вывести их на карту. 
Kibana умеет так делать через визуализацию Tile map

Но если я пытаюсь сам получить все записи, то  elasticsearch выдаёт, что hits=миллион, а самих записей выдает только 10 штук, в итоге я не могу отрисовать карту.

Нашёл опцию выдачи "size": 10000, но опять же, не более 10000 или менять настройки index.max_result_window.

Похоже, что чтобы выдать миллион, нужно использовать scroll api с проходом как бы окном?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [`From / Size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-from-size.html) в цикле (как вы сказали "окном").
Миллион записей пачкой обработать ресурсоёмко или невозможно, даже не смотря на настройки сервера.

Кроме того, рекомендую Вам аггрегировать записи перед получением, если это конечно допустимо в рамках задачи.